# Chaining in CompletableFuture to return first value

Tags: java, completable-future

I have some code that saves an entity to a database using `spring-data` and then performs some other work `foo()` and `bar()` that needs the `id` from the entity that has been saved. It looks like this:

```
private CompletableFuture<Void> save(MyEntity me) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = ContextAwareCompletableFuture
        .runAsync(() -> repository.save(me))
        .thenRunAsync(() -> foo(me))
        .thenRunAsync(() -> bar(me));
    return future;
}

private Foo foo(MyEntitiy me) {
    // Use the identifier for me to update some foo in another world
}

private Bar bar(MyEntitiy me) {
    // Use the identifier for me to update some bar in at another time
}
```

Now, I do not want to return `void` from my `save` method. I want to return a `MyEntity` so I tried:

```
private CompletableFuture<MyEntity> save(MyEntity me) {
    CompletableFuture<MyEntity> future = ContextAwareCompletableFuture
        .runAsync(() -> repository.save(me))
        .thenRunAsync(() -> foo(me))
        .thenRunAsync(() -> bar(me));
    return future;
}
```

This does not work since `runAsync` returns void. My method `repository.save()` returns the object I wish to return but that call is at the beginning of the chain. I need to save the object before I can do my `foo` and `bar`.

So next thing I tried is:

```
private CompletableFuture<MyEntity> save(MyEntity me) {
    CompletableFuture<MyEntity> future = ContextAwareCompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> repository.save(me))
        .thenApplyAsync((e) -> baz(e);
    return future;
}

private MyEntity baz(MyEntitiy me) {
    foo(me);
    bar(me);
    return me;
}
```

Now, that seems wrong to me. `Foo` and `Bar` will now have to be executed during the same stage and they might take some time.

How can I return the object saved in `repository.save()` after `foo` and `bar` has finished properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `foo` and `bar` may run concurrently, you may choose to chain on `save` instead of sequencing them:

```
private CompletableFuture<MyEntity> save(MyEntity me) {
    CompletableFuture<MyEntity> future = ContextAwareCompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> repository.save(me));
    CompletableFuture<Void> fooFuture = future
        .thenAcceptAsync((e) -> foo(e));
    CompletableFuture<Void> barFuture = future
        .thenAcceptAsync((e) -> bar(e));
    return future
        .thenCombine(fooFuture, (result, fooResult) -> result)
        .thenCombine(barFuture, (result, barResult) -> result);
}
```

Note I used `thenAcceptAsync` instead of `thenRunAsync` to avoid capturing `me`.  I avoided the capture in the end as well.

We can avoid one `thenCombine` if we return the entity on `fooFuture` and `barFuture`:

```
private CompletableFuture<MyEntity> save(MyEntity me) {
    CompletableFuture<MyEntity> future = ContextAwareCompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> repository.save(me));
    CompletableFuture<MyEntity> fooFuture = future
        .thenApplyAsync((e) -> { foo(e); return e; });
    CompletableFuture<MyEntity> barFuture = future
        .thenApplyAsync((e) -> { bar(e); return e; });
    return fooFuture
        .thenCombine(barFuture, (fooResult, barResult) -> fooResult);
}
```

Comment: Great, I ended up using the first suggestion since it was easier to follow what was going on.

Answer (score -1):

You could chain with a method that does stuff and returns the input:

```
.thenApply(e -> { foo(e); return e; }
```

Comment: Hmm, since `foo` is used already I guess you mean I create a new method `baz` that does this at the end?

Comment: @span What I guess he tried to convey is that in your original code you can replace `thenRunAsync(() -> bar(me));` with `thenApply( e -> {bar(me); return me;});`